# Why doesn't !gt equal to !gt with the stripos() function?

Tags: php, string, variables

I got a problem with string comparing in php, and i've done research thoughout te internet to no avail. So it's my turn asking the questions:
**The following is my code for comparing two strings, one from my database, and one from an irc chat. The problem is that this code won't compare correctly**

```
if('!gt' == $command)
```

^this don't work, neither do:

```
if(stripos('!gt', $command) === 0){
    echo "This is the correct command<br>";
    privmsg($channel, $GLOBALS['commands'][$i]['message']);
}
```

IRC input ($command) = !gt

My question is ultimately: *Why doesn't **!gt** equal to **!gt** with the stripos() function?*

Comment: What is the **exact** output of : `var_dump($command);` (Take the output from the source code)?

Comment: Show us the var_dump() value of `$command` and we might be able to explain

Comment: You've tagged this `arrays`.... any particular reason?

Comment: @MarkBaker On what do you bet :)? I bet it's hidden html tags or a weird character like zero width space

Comment: @Rizier123 that'd be my guess

Comment: @Rizier123 string '!gt
' (length=5)

Comment: What kind of abomination against programmers is a zero width space? D:

Comment: @MarkBaker The arrays tag was a fail, at first, I included more info, and a broader question, but i narrowed it, and forgot to remove the tag(sorry!).

Comment: `!gt` is only 3 characters but you have `5`.  `trim($command)`

Comment: @VelocityHD Try to use `trim($command)`

Comment: anyone having ideas as to where the two last characters may have come from? also, what can i do to remove it?

Comment: Ok, there. trim() worked! Thanks people!

Comment: Only one question, so i don't screw up on stackoverflow again, why did someone downvote my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like i got some extra characters with the string, so i had to use:

```
trim(string)
```

to remove the extra characters.

A big thanks to @rizier123, @MarkBaker and @AbraCadaver for the help :D

Comment: Also if you want to read more about trim, see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php (And don't forget Mark Baker :)